# Tem como passar uma rota especifica determinada por um id ? (Rotas Angular)

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, rotas, angular-routes

Ex :
Quero fazer um cadastro(Estou trabalhando com metadata)

Minha rota hoje {path:entidade/:idEntidade/cadastro component:CadastroComponent}

Onde o idEntidade é substituido dinamicamente quando clico,por ex: no menu cadastro clico em banco :

a rota passa a ser = {path:entidade/BANCO/cadastro component:CadastroComponent} abrindo o cadastro para o banco.

Oque eu quero fazer adicionar um id para cada idEntidade

se o idEntidade é = banco então o banco corresponde ao id 1 logo,  id:1= banco.

Quero que as rotas fiquem assim:

{path:/direct/:id ComponentCadastro}

Porém tenho que conferir id para saber qual cadastro abrir.

id:1= banco   id:2=filial

se o id for 1 a rota sera {path: direct/1 component: ComponenteCadastro},(e abrirá a pagina para fazer o cadastro do banco)

se o id for 2 a rota sera {path:direct/2 component : ComponenteCadastro}(e abrirá a pagina para fazer o cadastro da filial)

Preciso de ajuda pois não sei como fazer.

Comment: Não consegui compreender a sua dúvida. Tente disponibilizar algum código pra ficar mais claro

Answer (score 2):

Resolvi com dictionary typescript e this.router.navigate[()];

Answer (score 1):

Talvez isso ajude:

Você consegue capturar os parâmetros com o *ActivatedRoute* conforme como você  especifica o nome dos parâmetros e com isso você consegue pegar o */:IdEntidade/*.

```
idEntidade: number;

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){
    this.idEntidade = this.route.snapshot.params.idEntidade;
}
```

Com o *idEntidade*, no HTML do *ComponentCadastro*, você consegue demostrar qual componente de cadastro demonstre com o  *ngIf* :

```
<app-cadastro-banco *ngIf="idEntidade === 1"></app-cadastro-banco>
<app-cadastro-filial *ngIf="idEntidade === 2"></app-cadastro-filial>
```